# iCal4j ics file not importing to Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, icalendar

I'm having trouble importing a .ics file via the "Internet Calendars" option in Outlook.

The file is produced, I believe, by a Java applet. When I open the .ics file directly within Outlook 2010 it works fine, i.e. click on the link and open the downloaded file with Outlook. I've also validated it online with the validator mentioned in some Stack Overflow posts.

However, when I subscribe to the link via internet calendars I get the following error:

> The file "calendar" is not a valid Internet Calendar file

I haven't been able to work out what's going wrong here and the error message isn't particularly helpful.

Does anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved on this thread:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ical4j/forums/forum/368291/topic/6062163/index/page/1

Unfortunately, I only have access to the applet link and not any of the code used to produce the ics file itself so unless I can find a way to automatically parse the file and add in the line METHOD:PUBLISH I won't be able to add the feed in outlook.